# DesignInstance showing unexpected value

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

So I've been trying to get into DesignData for the WPF Designer. I have a page:

```
<src:BasePage xmlns:cal="Namespace&AssemblyInfo"
              xmlns:src="AnotherNamespace"
              x:Class="Actual_Class"
              x:TypeArguments="ActualClassArg"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"           
              mc:Ignorable="d" 
              d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=cal:ViewDesignMock,
                                               IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

...
                    <TextBlock x:Name="UserInstructionLabel"         
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding userInstruction}">
                    </TextBlock>
</src:BasePage>
```

The code behind for this page follows:

```
    public partial class InstructionPage : BasePage<InstructionViewController>
    {
        public InstructionPage() { }

        public InstructionPage(IDetectorControl detector, IBaser baser) : this()
        {         
            ViewModel = new InstructionViewController(detector, baser); //ViewModel is of BasePage
            DataContext = ViewModel.M_View;
            InitializeComponent();          
        }
   }
```

The ViewDesignMock is as follows:

```
    public class ViewDesignMock
    {
        public ViewDesignMock(){ }

        public System.String userInstruction
        {
            get => "TESTING";
        }
   }
```

What results is the design view displaying "userInstruction" for the Binding, and not "TESTING." As I'm still pretty new with this, I do have a few questions concerning what's going on. When can I expect the designer to reflect changes made to the DesignInstance model? On build? And why is it that I'm seeing the name of the property being shown on the binding, and what can I do to reflect the value instead of the name? I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I stumbled on this article written in 2016 in the microsoft, titled "Debug or disable project code in XAML Designer"

"For projects that target ARM or X64 processors, Visual Studio cannot run project code in the designer, so the Disable project code button is disabled in the designer."

My project is indeed targeting x64, is this restriction still valid?

Answer (score 0):

> When can I expect the designer to reflect changes made to the DesignInstance model? On build?

Yes, In the WPF design view, you need to refresh (Rebuild) the DesignInstance, the view will show the update value.

Without the related code. I create a simple on my side. It can show the value in the WPF design view instead of the property's name.

```
  public class ViewDesignMock : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewDesignMock() { }

    public System.String userInstruction
    {
        get => "TESTING22222222222222";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }


    //private string _userInstruction = "TESTING22666222";
    //public string userInstruction
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        return _userInstruction;
    //    }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        _userInstruction = value;
    //        OnPropertyRaised("userInstruction");
    //    }
    //}


}
```

[image]